# Disabling all auto completions and suggestions

Tags: autocomplete

I am using "Visual Studio Code" on Ubuntu. I would like to disable all auto completes, suggestions, drop down choice menus, etc. Like the man in "Blazing Saddles", "Suggestions? I doan need no stinkin' suggestions!". I have been searching the web for how to do this, but have only found answers that are nibbling around the edges. I need help!

Is there any master configuration item I can set to accomplish my goal (settings -> "don't talk back"?). Alternately, is there a list of configuration items (under "settings" maybe) that I have to set?

Thanks in advance.

I tried unchecking some obscure editor setting that was cited on the web. If it changed anything in the mountain of stuff I get back in the editor then I haven't noticed it.